# Parent Query does not see columns of subquery when returning using SELECT *

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently learning SQL using Oracle SQL developer.

While writing queries I came up with three different versions of the same query.

```
SELECT 
  sh.share_id
  FROM shares sh
    LEFT JOIN trades tr
      ON sh.share_id = tr.share_id 
  WHERE trade_id is NULL;

SELECT 
  sr.share_id
  FROM (SELECT sh.share_id, tr.trade_id
      FROM shares sh
    LEFT JOIN trades tr
      ON sh.share_id = tr.share_id) sr
  WHERE sr.trade_id is NULL;

SELECT 
  sr.share_id
  FROM (SELECT *
      FROM shares sh
    LEFT JOIN trades tr
      ON sh.share_id = tr.share_id) sr
  WHERE sr.trade_id is NULL;
```

The first two queries compile, run and return the same result set but when I try to run the third query I get a error on the second line of the third query.
"SR"."SHARE_ID": invalid identifier.
I know that * in the SELECT statement selects all columns so why Am I getting this error?

Comment: Does both tables has the "trade_id" columns?

Comment: Only the trades table has "the trade_id" column

Comment: Sorry it was not my intent to ask about the trade_id but the "share_id" is it on both tables or just one of then?

Comment: The "share_id" is in both the trades and shares tables.

Comment: The third query doesn't know which `share_id` you want to refer to. This is one of the reasons why `SELECT *` can be so bad.

Comment: Yeah I realized when I ran only subquery the table returned had columns share_id and share_id_1 even though the values for both columns are the same. Thank You for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading your comments, in your final query, the DBMS doesn't know which `share_id` to use for your `SELECT sr.share_id`.  AKA the `SELECT *` of your subquery is grabbing two `share_id` columns. You have to do something like your 2nd query.

Comment: Oh I just notice If I run the subquery in the FROM it includes share_id and share_id_1 in the return table as you mentioned it grabs the share_id in both tables. Thank You for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `select *` is selecting all columns from both tables, even those with the same name.  So, you are getting `share_id` twice.  A simple fix is to use `USING`:

```
SELECT sr.share_id
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM shares sh LEFT JOIN
           trades tr
           USING (share_id)
    ) sr
WHERE sr.trade_id is NULL;
```

Of course, tis only fixes the reference to `share_id`.